# What is the equivalent of getattr() in Julia

Tags: julia

What is the equivalent of Python's getattr() in Julia? I have tried the following meta-programming code, but it only works at the global scope, not inside a function scope.

```
type A
  name
  value
end

a = A("Alex",1)
for field in fieldnames(a)
   println(eval(:(a.$field)))
end
```

This will print out:

```
Alex
1
```

However, if the above is inside a function scope, then it won't work

```
function tmp()
  a = A("Alex",1)
  for field in fieldnames(a)
     println(eval(:(a.$field)))
  end
end

tmp()
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: a not defined
```

EDIT:
Thanks everybody for answering the question. Here are the links to the Julia's documentation on [getfield](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/?highlight=getfield#Base.getfield) and [setfield!](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/?highlight=getfield#Base.setfield!).

Answer (score 13):

You want to use [`getfield`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#Base.getfield).

```
julia> function tmp()
         a = A("Alex",1)
         for field in fieldnames(a)
            println(getfield(a, field))
         end
       end
tmp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> tmp()
Alex
1
```

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the [`getfield`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=getfield#Base.getfield) function:

```py
julia> type A
           name
           value
       end

julia> function foo()
           a = A("Alex", 1)
           for field in fieldnames(a)
               @show getfield(a, field)
           end
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
getfield(a,field) = "Alex"
getfield(a,field) = 1

julia>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will add the link to the getfield() from the Julia documentation (http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/?highlight=getfield#Base.getfield )